# how to get selected item index in form in j2me

Tags: java-me

I am appending 20 images in form by using loop.when i am scrolling these images up and down i want selected image index so that i can view bigger size of selected image.
i used this form.append(image)

is there any method or way  to get selected item index in form like in list there is getSelectedIndex.

plz help me and provide me gud solution ..

Answer (score 0):

The APIs for javax.microedition.lcdui.Form don't provide a means to get the selected item index, most likely because it wasn't designed for that kind of use. For the use case as described in your question, the correct approach would be to use javax.microedition.lcdui.List. In addition to determining the selected item, List also provides other useful APIs such as setting a select screen command for the items in the list.